# 3-Bit 2's Complement Circuit

Tags: logic-gates, binary, boolean-algebra

I want to design **3-Bit 2's Complement Circuit** but saw too many ways of it.
Also many of them were not described with detailed gate drawings.

So what is the best way to design 3-Bit 2's Complement Circuit with *minimum gates*?

Comment: Look at all the many ways you've seen of doing it and see which is the best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon me in case of any mis-conception, since this is my first answer here.

The easiest way I can figure out is through **K-Map**. There can be other methods too.

Let (F1 F2 F3) be the outputs with F1 as the most significant bit. And (x y z) be the inputs with x as most significant bit. Then, using the Karnaugh Map and truth table method, we can solve as follows:

```
F1 = ( !x & (y | z) ) | (x & !y & !z);
F2 = y ^ z (y xor z);
F3 = z;
```

So, in all, we require for 7 gates for F1 and 1 gate for F2 and short-wire for F3. In all we have 8 gates.

Note that this is a **cumulative count** containing three **NOT**, two **AND**, two **OR** and one **XOR** gate, you can always convert them into universal **NAND** gate count.

Comment: Do you realize that you probably just gave the OP their homework answer. Please do not persist doing this on this site.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for being more elaborate. @Michael Karas

Comment: @sharvil111 Your answer is not bad because of its goodness... It is bad because his question indicates that such a succinct answer would train the original asker into a bad habit of help vampiring.

Comment: I agree. Since this was my first answer in this community, I tried my best to explain the OP, and I was in a fear about lack if detailing. I assure you that, this mistake won't be repeated again @MickLH

Answer (score 0):

The best way if you want to do this in the older conventional design flow follows these steps.

1. Write down a full truth table of input states and corresponding output states.
2. For each bit output column in the truth table craft a Karnough map of the output '1's within the matrix of the input state bit values.
3. Use the Karnough map minimization technique to find groups of output '1's that basically show what inputs are don't-care for certain of the output groups.
4. Write the logic equations in AND/OR format for the minimal set of output groups that cover all the '1' positions.

There are plenty of web site resources that will describe each step of this process.

Answer (score 0):

The 8 gate solution is correct.  Though thinking through the basic definition of a 2s compliment also gives a clear solution:

To convert to 2s compliment, "invert each bit, add 1, discard the last carry".

So for a 3 bit binary input:
Start with 3 inverters, one for each input bit.
Each inverted output goes to a 2 bit adder, (an XOR paralleled with an AND).
The carry from each lower adder (AND) feeds to the next higher XOR input.
The extra 1 is entered at the first XOR spare input.
The last adder needs no carry. (so the last adder needs no AND).

The conversion can be verified by adding the input binary to the output binary, the result must always be 000 with a carry out from the last bit, (except at 000).